# Why is my alert not firing from the successful return of ajax?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

my ajax calls the controller and sends parameters successfully but I want to show an alert to my user before the page is submitted.  Why is my alert not showing.  Here's what I'm working with.  Please help me if you can.  Thanks!

```
var theParms = { selectedDate: "date", testing: "myTester" };
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Error/TimeCheck",
        data: theParms,
        datatype: "html",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

public ActionResult Timecheck( string selectedDate, string testing)
{
    return Content("hello " + selectedDate); 
}
```

Comment: Is your Timecheck method being hit? Are you sure?

Comment: Yes.  I put a breakpoint in the action to check.

Comment: Is your datatype:"html" correct? Have you tried to use __error__ option function to check if the ajax response fails?

Comment: Sorry you just lost me with: error option function to check if the ajax response fails? I'll have to do more research on ajax calls...still new to me.

Comment: Besides `success` there is `error` and `complete` as [options](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), just add an `error` element to the object you pass to `$.ajax` with `function() {debugger;}` and check if your browser (chrome) with open dev-console (ctrl+shift+i) stops at `debugger`.

Comment: check your console you might be got an error with code 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ajax is asynchronous, so it skips the success part. You can change the asynchronous bevavious of ajax by changing the "async:false" property. You can try this:

```
 var theParms = { selectedDate: "date", testing: "myTester" };
   $("#saveBtn").click(function () {
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Error/TimeCheck",
    data: theParms,
    async:false,
    datatype: "html",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    }
  });
 });
```

Comment: I removed the breakpoint from the action and the alert fired ok so I think the explanation must be associated with Naveen’s suggestion: The ajax is asynchronous, so it skips the success part.  I didn’t try the async:false because it fires ok but it must have something to do with the asynchronous behavior.  Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Your client expects the Ajax call to return HTML data (`datatype: "html"`). However, your ASP.NET MVC controller method returns just a string. It doesn't even set a content type.

Either return a proper HTML response on the server side or fix the expected datatype on the client side to match whatever the server returns. If you use Chrome's developer tools, you can easily see the effective content type in the network view.

I propose, you fix it like this:

```
var theParms = { selectedDate: "date", testing: "myTester" };
$("#saveBtn").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Error/TimeCheck",
        data: theParms,
        datatype: "text",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
});

public ActionResult Timecheck( string selectedDate, string testing)
{
    return Content("hello " + selectedDate, "text/plain"); 
}
```